# Subsequent dropout layers all connected to the first in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, lstm, dropout

So I just installed TensorBoard and looked at a deep LSTM I have been working on and saw something on the graph that I wasn't expecting.  I have 5 hidden LSTM layers, each followed by a dropout layer, and it shows that the first dropout layer is connected directly to each one of the 4 following dropout layers:

LSTM deep neural network graph:
[image: LSTM deep neural network graph]

What exactly is going on here?  I was expecting it all to just be in a simple straight line top to bottom.  Here's what my structure looks like in code, I didn't change very many of the default parameters...

```
# dataset.NUM_STEPS = 64
# dataset.NUM_FEATURES = 1109
# len(dataset.note_to_one_hot) = 123
# len(dataset.duration_to_one_hot) = 846
# len(dataset.offset_to_one_hot) = 140

inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(dataset.NUM_STEPS, dataset.NUM_FEATURES))
x = keras.layers.LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(.333)(x)
x = keras.layers.LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(.333)(x)
x = keras.layers.LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(.333)(x)
x = keras.layers.LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(.333)(x)
x = keras.layers.LSTM(units=512)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(.333)(x)

note_output = keras.layers.Dense(name="n", units=len(dataset.note_to_one_hot), activation='softmax')(x)
duration_output = keras.layers.Dense(name="d", units=len(dataset.duration_to_one_hot), activation='softmax')(x)
offset_output = keras.layers.Dense(name="o", units=len(dataset.offset_to_one_hot), activation='softmax')(x)

model = keras.models.Model(name=model_name, inputs=inputs, outputs=[note_output, duration_output, offset_output])
optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=6.66e-5, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
losses = {"n": "categorical_crossentropy", "d": "categorical_crossentropy", "o": "categorical_crossentropy"}
metrics = {"n": "categorical_accuracy", "d": "categorical_accuracy", "o": "categorical_accuracy"}
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=losses, metrics=metrics)
```

Comment: generally it is better to name all your layers to avoid confusions. 
Could you try to remove the input_shape argument for layers other than your 1st layer and check your model? Generally input_shape argument is used when your layer is the first layer of the model. Maybe that is creating these connections in the graph?

Comment: I just tried removing the input_shape argument, and the graph still looks exactly the same!

And I wouldn't know what to name the layers other than what they're automatically named.  lstm_# and dropout_# perfectly describes what type of layer and its location already.  The names of the output layers are only one letter because otherwise the progress bar text won't fit on a single line in the console.  That messes with keras printing the "\r" character and makes it write each step to a new line and just floods the console, making it impossible to view the loss/accuracy as it progresses

Comment: @mvers303 this is really interesting! I tried a toy example based on your model and visualized it on tensorboard. In this example, i didnt add any of your dropout layers. It gave a simple straight network. I removed only the first dropout and kept the rest. This graph had similar structure as yours with the dropout connection going to all other dropout layers from the second dropout layer.

Comment: @mevers303 I'm also having this strange dropout graph connection. Did you ever figure it out?